# Java Асинхронный процесс под Tomcat

Tags: java, многопоточность, tomcat

Добрый день!

Есть вопрос по созданию ассинхронных процессов в Tomcat.

**Вопрос такой:** как  под Tomcat пишут классы которые должны работать паралельно?

Нужно чтобы  раз в минуту процесс стягивал имформацию через SSH, а основной процесс будет обновлять страницу в соответствии с этой информацией.

Пишут ли это как-то особенно под Tomcat используя Web Services напрмер  или же используют обычную многопоточность Java SE?

Заранее благодарен

Comment: используют обычную многопоточность Java SE

Comment: а не проще ли на странице сделать скриптик, запрашивающий эту информацию с заданным периодом. Ну и отдельным потоком ее обновлять.

Comment: сделайте простой `java scheduler`, это обычная Java SE